# Change Angular typescript component from within nativeElement EventListener

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So my problem is that I would like to transfer information between my mouse down event listener and my 'myComponent' but (for example, change the value "h" to 100 on mouse down in the canvas. But I can't reach the variable because if I use the "this" prefix (like I did here) the this will refer t the HTMLCanvasElement not the component. ( i would like to change the coordinates of an object that uses 'h' as a coordinate in the canvas and I can't do it without this)

```
export class myComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('canvas', { static: true })
  canvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  private ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  h = 55;
  w = 55;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    this.canvas.nativeElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
      console.log(evt.offsetX);
      console.log(evt.offsetY);
       this.h=100
    }, false);
  }

}
```

Comment: Replace the function, `function(evt) { ... }`, with an arrow function `(evt) => { ... }`.

Comment: You can read about `this` and arrow functions here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-and-arrow-functions

Comment: It worked thank you! ^_^ I will read the source.

Comment: Please do not add SOLVED to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)